# How do I get the stat measure for only 1 specific sub-group

Tags: python

```
data.groupby('Income group')['Poorest (Wealth quintile)'].mean()
```

```
Income group
High income (H)             30.400000
Low income (L)               3.000000
Lower middle income (LM)     6.090909
Upper middle income (UM)    36.440000
Name: Poorest (Wealth quintile), dtype: float64
```

This code gives me the following output, but I only want Upper middle in the output. How do I do this?

Comment: Follow the suggestions in this thread to improve your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples

Comment: would appriciate for an upvote if it solves your problem my friend! welcome to StackOverflow

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You simply just do this:

```
result = data.groupby('Income group')['Poorest (Wealth quintile)'].mean()
print(result.loc['Upper middle income (UM)'])
```